# Phase relationships in AC circuits

Tags: passive-networks, phase

Is it wrong to use the mnemonics "ELI the ICE" [ From my understand means if its inductive current LAGS voltage and if its capacitive current LEADS]  in understanding the phase relationship of a Parallel RLC circuit? because I've just read in a book that its the opposite because given a parallel LC circuit,if current in the inductor is greater than current in the capacitor the current lags or if XC > XL current lags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mnemonics work fine and are for AC steady-state (phasor) conditions.  They are restricted to the individual elements, not the circuit as a whole. So, when you say "ELI", it refers to the current into the inductor with respect to the voltage across the inductor.

In the phasor diagram to the right i arbitrarily align the current to the 0 degree axis. Steady-state, positive frequency phasors rotate counterclockwise.  So, you can see the voltage is leading the current by 90 deg (it is also correct to say that it is lagging the current by 270 deg but we normally prefer to use the smaller angles when describing and that fits the mnemonic).

[image]

The circuit below is an inductor in parallel with a capacitor, fed from an ideal AC voltage source.  The top-right phasor diagram shows both element's current phasor referenced to the voltage across them (VAC).  The current coming from the source is the sum of these two (KCL).  In my example the capacitive current is larger (light blue).  When you add those two together you end up with a net resultant that is still capacitive (the bottom right phasor diagram).  So, as far as the source is concerned, the load just looks like a capacitor.  This is what @Reroute was describing concerning power factor correction.

When you introduce resistance you can now end up with a resultant current from the source that is somewhere between completely capacitive and completely inductive.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The way I always remember it is, capacitors store voltage, so causes the voltage to lag, inductors "store" current, so causes the current to lag

While I know the inductor one is a stretch, its worked for me,

The relationship does not change between series and parallel, and does not relate to how much current, only the inductive and capacitance values, this is why power factor correction fits capacitors in parallel with motor phases.

If you have some complex RLC network, then any series resistance with an inductive or capacitive element would reduce the phase shift, so that still does not involve the amount of current. only the values,

Comment: I think yours is good mnemonic too since it works.  My college roommate hated cats and that is how he remembered cathode as negative on a [diode](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/polarity/diode-and-led-polarity).